# Printing all objects in the inner array of a nested array based on input.value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching for a solution to my problem on StackOverflow for a few hours now and since I can't seem to find a fitting way to solve it I thought I would try to ask here myself.

So I'm trying to paste everything in an array into a section on a html document. Something like this, but only difference is I want to paste one of the profile arrays based on the value of a user input. Here is the code that worked as I wanted it on the first page minus the for loop so its not too long:

```js
suggestionSection.innerHTML += 
    `<div class="grid-item">
       <img src="${ profiles[i][0] }" width=75%>
       <h3>${ profiles[i][1] }</h3>
       <h4>Alder: ${ profiles[i][2] }</h4>
       <p>${ profiles[i][3] }</p>
       <input type="button" value="Kontakt ${ profiles[i][1] }">
    </div>`;
```

Here is the code that I'm struggling with that probably needs a lot of correcting:

```js
var choiceofAge = parseInt(ageInput.value);
var choiceofGender = genderInput.value.toLowerCase();
            
function showProfiles () {
    for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
        var age = profiles[i][2];
        var gender = profiles[i][5];
                
        if (choiceofAge === age && choiceofGender === gender) {
            suggestionSection.innerHTML = `
                <img src="${ profiles[i][0] }" width=75%>
                <h3>${ profiles[i][1] }</h3>
                <h4>Alder: ${ profiles[i][2] }</h4>
                <p>${ profiles[i][3] }</p>
                <input type="button" value="Kontakt ${ profiles[i][1] }">`;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? The problem is that nothing shows up when i click the button that runs the function and also my editor shows me `ERROR: Parsing error: Unexpected character '`'``if that makes a difference. `genderInput` and `ageInput` are defined with `getElementById` btw just didnt paste it on here.

If anyone has a suggestion, thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You did not really state what the problem is... Do you get an unexpected output? In that case, can you provide example input, and the expected output for it? Just guessing: did you mean `choiceofGender === gender` instead of `choiceofGender && gender`?

Comment: You need to use `.length` in the for: `for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++)`. Also it could be that you need to use `choiceofGender === gender` in the `if`.

Comment: @Peter B thank you i just happened to write it wrong on stack overflow but i edited now.I clarified in the post what the actual problem is. A little tired so i forgot to state what the real problem was. Nothing seems to show up in the section.

Comment: @trincot i meant `===` yes just mistyped when entering into StackOverflow post. But its correct in the post. Yeah im sorry i forgot to state what the real problem was, i added it to the post now to clarify. But yeah, nothing seems to come up even though console shows no errors.

Comment: The code that you provided works if I put it in a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerontheweb/ecbjw8ru/ You need to be more specific about exactly what is happening / what goes wrong on your end.